# Is there a formula for calculating or estimating the number of digits of a binary integer?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

ex : base 10(999) => 3 digits  ===  base 2(1111100111) => 10 digits

I am currently using a table to make this estimate, but it remains limited to 15 digits in base10 because under JS we remain blocked by MAX_SAFE_INTEGER is the following table (run snippet to see it).

How to extend this table by a formula, until 255 digits en base 10 ?

```js
const TDigits   = document.querySelector('#T-Digits tbody')
,     MaxDigits = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER.toString().length
;

var x9 = '9';

for (let n=1; n < MaxDigits; n++)
{
  let newRow = TDigits.insertRow(-1)

  newRow.insertCell(0).textContent = n
  newRow.insertCell(1).textContent = (x9-0).toString(2).length

  newRow.insertCell(2).textContent = Math.ceil(Math.log2(Math.pow(10,n)))
  
  x9 += '9';
}
```

```css
table { margin:1em}
table thead { background-color: cadetblue }
table td { text-align: center; padding: .2em .5em; border-bottom: 1px solid grey }
```

```html
<table id="T-Digits">
  <caption>Max digits corresponding</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr><td>base 10</td> <td>base 2</td><td> log </td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr><td>0</td> <td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[edit] adding Math.ceil(Math.log2(Math.pow(10,n))) from **Jaromanda X**, ;)

Comment: `Math.log2` should do it

Comment: @JaromandaX probably `Math.ceil(Math.log2(n))`, but note that numbers in JavaScript are always floating point so above 54 bits the real story is more complicated.

Comment: I am not very good with logarithms, would you have a useful formula, is it helpfull for 255 digits ?

Comment: @Pointy, I think `Math.ceil(Math.log2(n+1))` e.g Math.log2(16) is 4 - but you need 5 digits

Comment: I am a living breathing "off by 1" error incarnate

Comment: @Pointy - by the way, Math.ceil was right (I originally had Math.floor in the comment) just you need to add one to n :p

Comment: @MisterJojo, as Pointy pointed out (no pun intended) once you get beyond the Max integer things get complicated ... a formula probably wont help

Comment: I have added `Math.floor(Math.log2(n+1))`  but this is not what I expect..

Comment: try `Math.ceil` like I corrected

Comment: there is a distinct pattern - wonder how long it goes for

Comment: `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` means what it seems like it means. You cannot represent all discrete integers between that value and `Number.MAX_VALUE`; the "distance" between the discrete values gets bigger as the exponent gets bigger. That said, the formula for bit length should still be close to correct.

Comment: `@ Jaromanda X` Math.ceil is not better..

Comment: `@Pointy 5` MAX_SAFE_INTEGER is not a limitation for me, all numéric values are placed in a string. I use a Euclid Division for conversion. see my answer here :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56410743/how-could-i-count-bit-from-large-number-in-javascript/56411091#56411091

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
for (n = 1; n < 256; n +=1 ) {
    console.log(n, Math.ceil(Math.log2(Math.pow(10,n))));
}
```

And the values match as far as I can tell

Answer (score 0):

```
 ⌊log2(n)⌋ + 1
```

```js
var n = 123;
console.log(n, (n >>> 0).toString(2) );
var nb = Math.floor( Math.log2(n) ) + 1;
console.log( nb );
```

Comment: that's fine, but in my problem `n` is the number of digits used in base 10,  not its integer value

Comment: probably won't be accurate since '1' is one digit and also '9' but '1' is '1' and '9' is '1001' so you need more info on the data.

Comment: this calculation serves me to estimate the maximum number of cycles in my Euclidean division (I have another faster version in hexa calculus) see => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56410743/how-could-i-count-bit-from-large-number-in-javascript/56411091#56411091